# How to implment padding to the right in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an icon that I have declared  in my application tag in the manifest file as `android:icon="@drawable/ic_myIcon"`

This icon is too close to the heading on the left how can I padd it to the right or some other way to insert space.

Thanks

Comment: re-export your icon again with padding. Here is a tool made by a Google design advocate, Roman Nurik.
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is the following:

```
android:paddingRight= "5dp"
```

You can change the amount of padding you need by increasing or descreasing the `dp` size

Alternatively you can also use margins instead of paddings.
Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: is `paddingRight` available in `application` tag?

Comment: checkout question, person wants it in application tag

Comment: It cannot be done in the manifest. It needs to be done in the layout xml file

Comment: That is what i am telling you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:paddingRight` or `android:paddingEnd`. In new APIs to handle RTL locale should be use `android:paddingEnd`. Also you can use  `android:layout_marginRight` or `android:layout_marginEnd`.

For example :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"  
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />
```

Or

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"  
    android:paddingEnd="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible, but try create this drawable and set as icon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/your_icon_res_image" />
    </item>
    <item android:right="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```